# How do I pull the second td tag from a table using Excel-VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, html-table

I'm trying to pull the second td tag, or the US Ten Year Treasury rate from https://www.bankrate.com/rates/interest-rates/federal-funds-rate.aspx using Excel VBA. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Ten_Year_Treasury()

' Record the US Ten Year Treasury rate from https://www.bankrate.com/rates/interest-rates/federal-funds-rate.aspx
Range("A2").ClearContents

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False

ie.navigate "https://www.bankrate.com/rates/interest-rates/federal-funds-rate.aspx"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

Set Element = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("table-inline__caption")

For Each htmlEle In Element

    With Sheets("10-Year Treasury")
        .Range("A2").Value = htmlEle.Children(0).innerText
    End With

Next

ie.Quit

'Remove Underline
Range("A2").Font.Underline = False
'Make Font Bold
Range("A2").Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

I know it has something to do with my "Element", and I've seen videos where they talk about using "children" or "sibling". Advice on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the problem - what happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong class name and in so doing are selecting the caption rather than the table. You can use a css class selector combined with nth-of-type to get 2nd td. I use one of the class values present in the table element.

```
.Range("A2").Value = ie.document.querySelector(".table-inline td:nth-of-type(2)").innerText
```

As that content is static you can use a faster xhr rather than browser to retrieve value. I show a variety of ways of then getting the node you want.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInterestRate()
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.xmlhttp60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    'required VBE (Alt+F11) > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library ;  Microsoft XML, v6 (your version may vary)

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.xmlhttp60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.bankrate.com/rates/interest-rates/federal-funds-rate.aspx", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = html.querySelectorAll(".table-inline td")(1).innerText
    'html.querySelector(".table-inline").rows(1).cells(1).innertext
    'html.querySelector(".table-inline").rows(1).children(1).innertext
    'html.querySelector(".table-inline td + td").innertext
    'html.querySelector(".table-inline td").nextsibling.innertext

End Sub
```

Read about:

1. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)
2. [xhr](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)
3. [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)
4. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)